# why is my ControllerAdvice not working in spring boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I use spring boot and spring security, and I want to add error handler for my application, this my ControllerAdvice :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionController  {

    public static final String DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW = "error";

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView defaultError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e)
            throws Exception {

        if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(e.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class) != null)
            throw e;
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("exception", e);
        mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
        mav.setViewName(DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW);
        return mav;
    }

}
```

and this my snippet error.html code (using thymeleaf) :

```
<div class="container">
        <h1 th:inline="text">Error</h1>
        <p th:text="${exception}"></p>
        <p th:text="${url}"></p>
</div>
```

and this spring security configuration snippet code :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().anyRequest()
        .fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
        .failureUrl("/login?error").and().logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access?error");

}
```

If I try to access my application use wrong URL, object exception and url in GlobalExcetionController doesnt render in error.html, why ?

[UPDATE]

My ControllerAdvice doesn't work only if error 404 , but the other errors it works, how to set ExceptionHandler to handle 404 error ?

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]

I add this @Bean to my spring boot config

```
@Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
        return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {

                ErrorPage error404Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
                        "/error404.html");
                container.addErrorPages(error404Page);

            }
        };
    }
```

for error404.html must be locate in static folder

thank to Reference :
http://www.sporcic.org/2014/05/custom-error-pages-with-spring-boot/